# My validation breaks sometimes

Tags: python-3.x

In my code, I am validating the user's input of a GTIN code.If the user enters anything that is not a number, 8 digits long and not on my text file, it outputs `Product Not Found`, however when testing when I enter an anything other than a number, it works fine. However, when I enter a single number like 0 it completely breaks and says `Quantity is not defined`, Quantity is one of my variables, I am not sure why is says that.

EDIT: when I enter 0, its output `Product Not Found`, however still gives me the error.

```
file = open("read_it.txt" , "r")
for line in file:
            line = line.strip('\n')
            print(line)
allprice=[]
while True:
    GTIN=(input("please enter GTIN for product or press enter for receipt"))
    if(GTIN==''):
       final = sum(allprice)
       final=str(final)
       print("total cost {0:33} £{1}".format("is",final))
       break
    else:
        if GTIN.isnumeric() and len(GTIN)==8 and GTIN in open('read_it.txt').read():
            while True:
                Quantity=""
                Quantity=(input("Please enter the Quantity"))
                if Quantity.isdigit():
                    break
                else:
                    print("enter a number!")
        else:
            print("Product Not Found")

        with open("read_it.txt", "r") as text_file:
            for items in text_file:
                line = items.strip('\r\n').split(",")
                if GTIN in items:
                    product = line[1]
                    indprice = line[2]
                    finprice = float(indprice)* float(Quantity)
                    finprice=int(finprice)
                    print("{:<10} {:<10} {:<10} £{:<10} £{:<10}".format(GTIN,product,Quantity,indprice,finprice))

    allprice.append(finprice)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are defining Quantity within the if block. Since "0" is not 8 digits long, Quantity is never defined and an error is thrown due to float(Quantity). Consider defining Quantity outside of if block.

Comment: thanks for answering, but I fixed it. It was because the with open as text_file section of the code was not indented with the Quantity section, so when I entered 0 it would skip the asking for quantity and straight to the calculations. check new code.